# What is the definition of a "Clustering Feature" in BIRCH algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, data-mining, clustering

The [paper for BIRCH](https://www.cs.sfu.ca/CourseCentral/459/han/papers/zhang96.pdf) (a clustering algorithm) contains definitions of a Clustering Feature (CF) where the notation is unclear (cf. PDF page 3 / section 4).

A cluster contains *N* *d*-dimensional entries $ \{ \vec{X}_1, \vec{X}_2, \dots, \vec{X}_N \} $ and its CF is composed of three values.

1. **N** the number of elements (straight forward)
2. $ \vec{LS} $ "linear sum of the elements" $ \sum_{i=1}^N \vec{X}_i $
3. $ SS $ "square sum of the N data points" $ \sum_{i=1}^N \vec{X}_i^2 $

The third value seems to cause confusion and is throwing me off. Let's start with the paper's definition.

I am parsing the notation as $ \sum_{i=1}^N \vec{X}_i^2 = \vec{X}_1^2 + \vec{X}_2^2 + \dots + \vec{X}_N^2 $. Now I am left with $ \vec{X}^2 $ and to my current understanding a dot/scalar product has to be applied, e.g.
$ \vec{X}^2 = \vec{X} \cdot \vec{X} = \sum_{j=1}^d x_j^2 $ where $x_j$ is an Element in $ \vec{X} = ( x_1, x_2, \dots , x_d ) $.

On the other hand, there are plenty of lectures/slides providing examples in which the value is not a scalar, but the element-wise squared sum, while the notation in the respective definition does not reflect this. The [German Wikipedia article](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIRCH#Clustering-Algorithmus) even states $ SS $ is a "d-dimensional vector".

Basically they are doing it like this, using the earlier notation: $ \vec{X}_i = ( x_{i,1}, x_{i,2}, \dots , x_{i,d} ) $
$ \vec{SS} = (\sum_{i=1}^N x_{i,1}, \sum_{i=1}^N x_{i,2}, \dots, \sum_{i=1}^N x_{i,d}) = (x_{1,1}^2 + x_{2,1}^2 + \dots + x_{N,1}^2, ... ) $.

In the end the sum of the components would be the same.

Why is are those examples doing it differently? Am I missing something?

---

**Examples describing SS as a scalar**

- [example implementation in C++](https://github.com/sanket1729/birch-clustering-algorithm/blob/master/CFTree.h#L152)
- [UCLA lecture slides (ppt, slide 9)](https://oak.cs.ucla.edu/~sia/present/birch.ppt)

**Examples describing SS as a d-dimensional vector**

- [Illinois lecture recording (youtube, around 2:44)](https://youtu.be/xw3RwYs7fUM?t=2m44s)
- [Data Mining: Concepts and Techniques (Book, page 25)](http://hanj.cs.illinois.edu/cs412/bk3/10.pdf#page=25)
- [Italian lecture slides (page 69)](http://www.mind.disco.unimib.it/public/opere/139.pdf#page=69)

*Edit: Added links to paper and examples, fixed typos.*

Comment: You should probably provide links to the various references. Presumably the actual algorithm comes out the same, but there might be several ways to present it.

Comment: Do you have a link a  freely available copy of the paper you're referring to?  Providing a full citation and a link to a copy of the paper might help.  I can see multiple things that notation might be referring to; and the best way to figure out what is intended might be to look at the context.

Comment: I added links to the some example sources, I added a link to the paper in question, which can be found online, all other source are paywalled, I hope this is unproblematic.

I might elaborate on the purpose of those values (context), which might give additional insight.